# Xamarin Android : Reposition Buttons/ Items to fit screen

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

Im currently making a app which has five buttons. At the moment I have 3 nested LinearLayouts with a total of five buttons, layout 1 has 2 buttons, layout 2 has 2 buttons, and layout 3 has 1 button.

[Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJuH.png)

So my question is, what is the best way to make this kind of layout responsive to different screen sizes? As in how would I go about make the layout and all the buttons reposition themselves to all fit nice and neatly on on the screen.

Im new to the world of Android development so if im missing something I apologize.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [GridLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/)

Comment: Would that layout change the buttons around depending on the screen size though?

Comment: Then i think you need to use something like
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
on your images to make it fill out the container in which they are in.

Comment: should be match_parent instead of fill_parent (it's deprecated)

Comment: I have tested the gridlayout and it doesnt seem to be the best. Plus I can get it to rearrange the buttons when running the app on different size devices. Would Fragments be the answer to my problem?